# Assigning noop to a variable

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I was digging into the [Angular utils](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/util.ts) source code and just encountered the following line:

```
export const NOOP: any = () => {};
```

Well, above is kind of obvious. Declare a variable which doesnt do any operation.
Now Inside the same library I have the following method:

```
export function resolveViewDefinition(factory: ViewDefinitionFactory): ViewDefinition {
  let value: ViewDefinition = VIEW_DEFINITION_CACHE.get(factory) !;
  if (!value) {
    value = factory(() => NOOP);
    value.factory = factory;
    VIEW_DEFINITION_CACHE.set(factory, value);
  }
  return value;
}
```

What would be the effect of just not having that line in place and commenting it out and have the block as follows:

```
  if (!value) {
    // value = factory(() => NOOP);
    value.factory = factory;
    VIEW_DEFINITION_CACHE.set(factory, value);
  }
```

Could someone elaborate more on this line:

```
value = factory(() => NOOP);
```

and shed more lights on it? I can see what is happening but I cant understand the effects of eliminating it.

Comment: I assume the factory function expects a function which returns an object (in this case it is empty object), than it "enriches" that object with some things (functions, other properties..). At the moment it is an empty object that it enriches, but maybe in some cases it will be an object that already has some things I guess

Comment: You didn't explain the potential effect of not having it in place. What will happen and how it is different?

Comment: Without that line it will have an error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'factory' of undefined`.

Comment: `if(!value)` means that value is `undefined` or `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resolveViewDefinition` function is used for getting view definition. First it tries to get `value` from the cache and if there is no cached value then it is calling `ViewDefinitionFactory`.

`ViewDefinitionFactory` takes function as parameter. Why?

```
/**
 * Factory for ViewDefinitions.
 * We use a function so we can reexecute it in case an error happens and use the given logger
 * function to log the error from the definition of the node, which is shown in all browser
 * logs.
 */
export interface ViewDefinitionFactory { (logger: NodeLogger): ViewDefinition; }
```

We do not need to log errors when we are just getting `ViewDefinition` so it is called with `NOOP` function.

But when we get error during executing some action within template angular is running this factory with `NodeLogger`to determine which node caused the error.

Let's see example **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview)**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h2 (click)="x()">Hello</h2>`
})
export class App {}
```

Here is factory

```
function View_App_0(l) {
  return jit_viewDef1(0,[
      (l()(),jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,1,'h2',[],null,[[
        null,
        'click'
      ]
    ],function(v,en,$event) {
      var ad = true;
      var co = v.component;
      if (('click' === en)) {
        var pd_0 = (co.x() !== false);
        ad = (pd_0 && ad);
      }
      return ad;
    },null,null)),
    (l()(),jit_textDef3(null,['Hello']))
  ]
  ,null,null);
}
```

1) Running application

```
function resolveViewDefinition(factory) {
    var value = ((VIEW_DEFINITION_CACHE.get(factory))); // we haven't cached it yet 
    if (!value) { // value is undefined 
        value = factory(function () { return NOOP; }); //get ViewDefinition but do not log errors
        value.factory = factory; // save link to the factory so it can be used later
        VIEW_DEFINITION_CACHE.set(factory, value); // store factory
    }
    return value;
}
```

2) After clicking on `Hello`

```
((logViewDef.factory))(nodeLogger); // use saved link to call factory with logger
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent job and explanation. You certainly deserve way more than an up-vote.